# Texture looking strange in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

So, I'm having this problem where the face texture I imported in unity looks weird.

What it is supposed to look like:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/oG8IA.png

What it looks like (Unity Inspector):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/nFEO8.png

Red, Green, Blue, and Alpha channels.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lr3a2.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/omxRu.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4qHjj.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/nwpOt.png

If anyone knows how to fix this, please answer the question. Any help will be appreciated.
Sorry, If this is too short. I'm new to stackoverflow, so I don't really know how to question properly but I hope this is enough.

Answer (score 0):

In the inspector, tick the checkbox labeled "Alpha Is Transparency", then hit "Apply".

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you're going to do with that texture but try to change the texture type from **Default** to **Sprite (2D and UI)** and hit apply. Maybe that's what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Click on the texture (the actual image), click the box "Alpha is transparency" and hit apply. Then unclick it and hit apply.